# Window Rezing in Android

Tags: android

I want window of my app to be resized when soft keyboard is launched. I thus added following tag to main activity in manifest.xml file
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
however even at time of app lunch keyboard is displayed and window is resized.

I want that at launch atleast keyboard not to be displayed automatically and window to be resized. only when some one is type should the window resizing should occur.

any guidance

just to further add I have editText which gets the control at time of launch. before adding  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" , complete screen use to get displayed and when I touched to type was keyboard displayed. I want the same behavior, that is keyboard should not to be displayed by default but displayed and window resized when someone touches to type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Activity Attribute by adding this to your Manifest File [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Like so, but haven't tried it.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode

<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" . . . >
```

How the main window of the activity interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard.

You can also refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

Comment: perfect adding stateHidden tag along with adjustResize did the trick. Thanks Ric:)

Answer (score 0):

Do below changes to your code

To hide the keyboard on activity launch add below code

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

To show keyboard when edittext gets focused, use below code

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        view.requestFocus();
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
    }
```

Call `hideSoftKeyboard()` in your onCreate method.

Once edittext gets focused use below code.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Focused",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE); // Resizing window programatically
                showSoftKeyboard(view);
            }
        });
```